# How to access dual cameras simultaneously?

Tags: android, camera

Does anyone know if it is possible to use multiple cameras on Android device at once?
For example, recording or previewing via front and back camera simultaneously.

Some Android devices can switch between them but I would like to know if they can work at the same time.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is included in some Samsung devices (e.g. Galaxy S IV, Galaxy Note 3).

Samsung devices implement this function in additional JNI library and it is done low level with usage of OpenGL and access to camera API.

I can provide some details if needed ( I am working on similar feature right now but I am going to modify PDA).

In general case, if you ask for API, there is no such feature for Android devices.

Comment: could you please point to some links for using it on samsung devices? maybe samples?